# Change over-the-air sync settings in iPad

Tags: ipad, icloud

My iPad is constantly popping out storage almost full message. When I link my iPad to iTunes on my PC I could see in my summary the bar for Others is the biggest culprit.

When I click on the Info button, it states that bookmarks are being synced with my iPad over the air from iCloud. How do I change the over-the-air settings in my iPad? What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Over-the-air settings are set on the device. Open Settings and browse to the setting you wish to change, then change it. The settings can't be changed in iTunes.

For example, to prevent Safari bookmarks syncing, open Settings → iCloud and disable Safari.